# WPF: Setting background image for Tab Headers in Tab Control

Tags: wpf, header, tabcontrol

Can someone please guide me how to set a background image for tab Headers in a TabControl. I dont want to replace the header text with an image, i want to display text and set an image in the background of the header.

Answer (score -1):

Ok Solved. 
The following changes the Tab Header background image. Switching to a different background image when a tab is selected.

```
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                    <Grid Name="gTabBG">
                                        <Grid.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush x:Name="tabBGImg" ImageSource="tab_normal.png" />
                                        </Grid.Background>
                                            <!-- other contents -->
                                        <Border Name="Border"  >
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            ContentSource="Header"
                                            Margin="10,2"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Trigger.Setters>
                                                    <Setter TargetName="gTabBG" Property="Background">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="tab_selected.png" />
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Trigger.Setters>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                                <Trigger.Setters>
                                                    <Setter TargetName="gTabBG" Property="Background">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="tab_normal.png" />
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Trigger.Setters>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Now you have to make a style for each tab item thats horrible